# Event reference is lost when waiting for a Promise

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have a function where I receive an event and push something on that event property:

```
map.addEventListener('contextmenu', async (e) => {
   const { Label } = await reverseGeoCode(getPosition.lng, getPosition.lat)

   e.items.push(addContextItem(Label, null)))
})
```

but for some reason `e` is getting lost while waiting for the `Label` to return. Why is that?

Comment: Try to console.log 'e' before and after the execution and post your results.

Comment: @AdiDarachi both objects look the same before and after. But the e.items.push is suppose to create a menu, which will not appear when it is awaiting the function before. All is working well when the await will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it this way:

> ```
> // add context menu listner  
> map.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
>     // reverse geocode at the point of click if not already
>     if (notReverseGeocoded) {
>         clickCoords = map.screenToGeo(e.viewportX, e.viewportY);
>         var reverseGeocodingParameters = {
>             prox: clickCoords.lat + "," + clickCoords.lng + ",200",
>             mode: 'retrieveAddresses',
>             maxresults: 1,
>             language: 'en'
>         };
>         geocoder.reverseGeocode(reverseGeocodingParameters, function(result){
>             try {
>                 address = result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.Address.Label;
>                 notReverseGeocoded = false;
>                 // disptach to the context menu event again to add results to the 
>                 // context menu
>                 map.dispatchEvent(e);
>             } 
>             catch (e) {
>                 console.log(e);
>             }
>         }, function(e){
>             console.log(e);
>         });
>
>     }
> ```